# GitKraken file encoding

Tags: encoding, gitkraken

I use Visual Studio to develop my code. My files are encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.
As VS doesn't allow to stage hunk a files, I use GitKraken to do so.
But when I stage a hunk a file with GitKraken, the encoding of the file change from UTF-8 with BOM to Western European (Windows).
How to avoid GitKraken to change my file encoding?

Comment: Would love to know as well. About to rule out GitKraken company wide due to this perplexing behavior

Comment: This is still going on. Support said it was a known issue back in April 2020. Not fixed as of v7.3.2

Comment: Upvote this issue here: https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/192991/support-for-additional-file-encoding